# How to determine where a Bash script was interrupted

Tags: bash

How can I determine where a Bash script was interrupted?

My code

```
trap stop exit

stop()
{
  echo "Script error"
  echo "File name: ?"
  echo "Line num : ?"
}

r1 . /tmp/1 || exit 1
r2 . /tmp/2 || exit 1
..
..
r3541 . /tmp/3541 || exit 1
r3542 . /tmp/3542 || exit 1
```

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap stop exit

stop()
{
  echo "Script error"
  echo "File name: $0"
  echo "Line num : $l"
}

r1 . /tmp/1 || { l=$LINENO; exit 1; }
r2 . /tmp/2 || { l=$LINENO; exit 1; }
..
..
r3541 . /tmp/3541 || { l=$LINENO; exit 1; }
r3542 . /tmp/3542 || { l=$LINENO; exit 1; }
```

Comment: And what is var 'l' ?

Comment: I copy current line number ($LINENO) to variable $l and print $l in your function stop.

Comment: How is this possible? Variable name 'l' is important?

Comment: @IngDedek It's just a global variable that the `stop` function uses. Since `LINENO` is the number of the line it appears on, you need to save its current value somewhere that `stop` can reference.

Comment: $LINENO is the important part. It is set by the bash. $l has been freely chosen by me. Feel free to replace all $l by $foo or $cyrus or $ing_dedek.